# Screen size does not follow the first device orientation change (SwiftUI, iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

I need to identify the screen's height and width every time the iOS v16.4 phone's orientation changes (Xcode 14.2).

I use UIScreen.main.bounds.size for that. However, it works in a weird way:

- when the app starts with the phone in portrait:

> height=736 width=414

- When I rotate the phone to Landscape for the first time, nothing changes:

> height=736 width=414

- Returning the phone back to Portrait swaps the values, but now they are reversed for Portrait:

> height=414 width=736

- All subsequent swaps between Landscape and Portrait change the height/width, but they are reversed, i.e.:

> In Landscape: height=736, width=414
> In Portrait:  width=414, height=736

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.Publisher(center: .default, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        var orientation = "Unknown  :"
            if Orientation.isPortrait {
                orientation = "Portrait :"
            }
            if Orientation.isLandscape {
                orientation = "Landscape:"
            }
        print("\(orientation) width=\(screenSize.width)     height=\(screenSize.height)")
    }
}
```

}

...and the outputs, starting with the initial launch and through sequential changes of the phone's orientation between portrait and landscape:

```
 Portrait: width=414.0     height=736.0  
Landscape: width=414.0     height=736.0  
 Portrait: width=736.0     height=414.0  
Landscape: width=414.0     height=736.0  
 Portrait: width=736.0     height=414.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Just for reference, I use a custom struct to be able to identify the orientation at the App's launch as well:

```
struct Orientation {
    static var isLandscape: Bool {
        get {
            let orientation = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene)?.interfaceOrientation
            return orientation!.isLandscape
        }
    }
    static var isPortrait: Bool {
        get {
            let orientation = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene)?.interfaceOrientation
            return orientation!.isPortrait
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by giving some time for the device to "think" about it for a moment. Meaning: first the device is rotated, then "think about it for a little while" and finally update the boundaries. The "little while" is a tenth of a second, so the user usually doesn't realize this lag.

Here is the code:

```
        
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                
            // Give a moment for the screen boundaries to change after
            // the device is rotated
            Task { @MainActor in
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.1))
                withAnimation {
                    screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
                    screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Fingers crossed 0.1 sec is enough for any imaginable scenario :)